# IDE for jenkins plugin developement

Tags: plugins, jenkins-plugins, webstorm

i am going to create or develop a new jenkins plugin. is WebStorm IDE supports to develop jenkins plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

No. WebStorm is not suitable for developing Jenkins plugins - it supports neither java nor maven. Please try Intellij IDEA (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-IntelliJIDEA)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using NetBeans. For the very same reasons which the website has stated.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-NetBeans